# Tengo problemas al actualizar mi proyecto en Angular de la versión 11 a la 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, update, cli

Buenas tardes estimados me llevo el día tratando de pasar de Angular 11 a la versión 12 siguiendo la guía de Angular. Resulta que del código que me da la guía, ejecute primero este codigo `npx @angular/cli@12` y el cli se me actualizo de la 11 a la versión 12, pero luego al ejecutar el siguiente código para actualizar que es este: `update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12 --allow-dirty` y me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nose si debo actualizar typescript pero entonces siguiendo la guia de angular ejecuto este otro codigo `ng update` que se supone lo actualizaría pero en el package.json no veo que se me actualice el typescript, pueden verlo en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que puedo agregar la bandera --force para omitir la advertencia pero esto no me vendrá con problemas más adelante? mi intención es actualizar el proyecto hasta la versión 13 de angular.

Agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda estimados
Pdt: estas son las dependencias que tengo en mi package.json:

```
{
  "name": "pasarela-de-pago",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/localize": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.14",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.3",
    "@schematics/angular": "^11.2.18",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "ng": "^0.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.18",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Intenta instalándola manualmente `npm install typescript@latest` y luego actualiza el proyecto a ver. Alternativamente ejecuta `npm update`.

Comment: Se me actualizo todo le proyecto a la versión 12 brother, me toco indicar la versión que se requería de typeScript que era la 4.2.3, solo me salió este mensaje de error pero ya quedo todo bien:  "(node:2056) [DEP0147] DeprecationWarning: In future versions of Node.js, fs.rmdir(path, { recursive: true }) will be removed. Use fs.rm(path, { recursive: true }) instead
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)".....Ahora me queda pasarlo a la versión 13 y poder continuar con el proyecto, muchas gracias de verdad y que pena que ando con muchas preguntas últimamente

Comment: Que no te de pena, para eso es este sitio. Da la casualidad de que siempre aparezco yo xD, pero si no soy yo será otro. ¿Cómo te funcionó? ¿Con lo que te dije o hiciste otra cosa? Ese warning no es importante, estoy seguro no es ni de tu código porque eso es como tal `fs` ni node nunca llegan al front. Debe ser de alguna librería que ya tendrá que actualizarlo.

Comment: Respóndete tu mismo para que futuras personas con la misma inquietud encuentren una solución.

Comment: Jajajaja si siempre apareces vos, pero se lo agradezco mucho, estoy en esta parte de integrar Paypal en una pasararela de pagos no se si te acuerdas, y me toca actualizarlo a la versión 13 porque si te acuerdas en el post pasado omitimos una pre dependencias entonces ahora cuando ejecutaba el servidor me a parecía varios arrores que decian que la libreria ngx-paypal requería de Angular 13, Pero bueno hay vamos step by step. Tu solución me ayudo en este caso solo que en vez de instalar la ultima versión de TypeScript instale la que se requería según el mensaje de alerta que me salio